# AI or simulated approach for 4 player spades

Tags: ai, card-game

I’ve read the strategies but would like to learn better moves.

Sometimes watching a simulated AI game with take backs allows me to learn how to eventually play better.

For 2 player it is fairly simple. 4 player card games such as spades, how would one go about this using modern AI? Does anything similar exist?

Comment: What strategies have you read? In what way do you want your new AI strategy to play "better"?